# Retrieve Field Value from Map

Tags: map

I am creating a batch process that looks at all records for the custom object `enrollment__c` that have a null `account_team__c` field.  That field is a lookup to the `account_team__c` custom object. The naming convention of that `account_team__c` object is the year and the account name.  So something like `2022 Acme Inc`  The map that I created contains a string and a custom object.  I declare the map with the following:

`Map<String, List<Account_Team__c>> accountAtsMap2 =new Map<String, List<Account_Team__c>> ();`

Everything gets populated in the map as expected but when I to add code to update the missing value, I get an error, `Variable does not exist: id`

Here is a record from the map (via debug)

```
14:36:29:027 USER_DEBUG [139]|INFO| 4 here is the ATName (Account_Team__c:{Id=a02S000000H0up9IAB, Name=2022 Test Prospect 1, Account_del__c=001S000001KbEBWIA3, Year__c=2022})
```

This is the line that won't save in VS because of the variable does not exist: id error:

`system.debug(logginglevel.info, ' 4 here is the ATName ' + accountAtsMap2.get(atName).id);`

Am I getting this error because I'm using a string instead of an ID in my map?  Here is the full code:

```
        global void execute(Database.BatchableContext ctx, List<Sobject> scope){

          // Cycle through the first time to build a list of related account Id's from the ES's queried
          //also add the enrollment summary to a list to be used later in code
        List<Id> accountIds = new List<Id>();
        for (sObject s : scope) {
            Health_Enrollment_Summary__c es = (Health_Enrollment_Summary__c)s;
            accountIds.add(es.account__c);
        }

           // Retrieve a list of all account teams using account id from ES's queried
        List<Account_Team__c> atList = [
            Select Id, Name, Account_del__c, Year__c, Account_del__r.name
            from Account_Team__c
            where Account_del__c in : accountIds];
          //create a map to hold the account id and related account team records
        Map<String, List<Account_Team__c>> accountAtsMap2 =new Map<String, List<Account_Team__c>> ();

          //populate the map with Account Team Name / Account Team
        for (Account_Team__c at : atList) {
              //create name of account team to use for lookup into map
            string tempAtname =  at.year__c + ' ' + at.Account_del__r.Name ;
            string AtName;
              //trim name to a max of 80 charachters 
            if (tempAtName.length()>80){
                AtName = tempAtName.substring(0,80);
            }
            else{
                AtName = tempAtName;
            } 
            List<Account_Team__c> tempList2 = new List<Account_Team__c>(); 
            if (accountAtsMap2.containsKey(ATName)) {
                tempList2 = accountAtsMap2.get(AtName);
            }
            tempList2.add(at);
            accountAtsMap2.put(Atname, tempList2);
        }  //end for loop for scope

        //test looping accountAtsMap2
      for (sObject s : scope) { 
            Health_Enrollment_Summary__c es = (Health_Enrollment_Summary__c)s;
            string tempAtname =  es.year__c + ' ' + es.Account__r.Name ;
            string AtName;
              //trim name to a max of 80 charachters 
            if (tempAtName.length()>80){
                AtName = tempAtName.substring(0,80);
            }
            else{
                AtName = tempAtName;
            } 
              //if es record has the account team field null, update 
            if(es.account_team__c == null){
                system.debug(logginglevel.info, ' 3 here is the ATName ' + AtName);
                if (accountAtsMap2.containsKey(AtName)) {
                    system.debug(logginglevel.info, ' 4 here is the ATName ' + accountAtsMap2.get(atName).Year_);
                   // es.account_team__c = accountAtsMap2.get(atName).Id;
               
                    //fill in the account team fields on ES
                   // system.debug(logginglevel.info, '2 here is the es with missing AT' + es.Name);
                }
            }
        }  //end of for loop on scope
    }  //end of execute method
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined the map `accountAtsMap2` as key `string` to value `List<Account_Team__c>`. So when you call `accountAtsMap2.get(atName)` it returns `List<Account_Team__c>` (may be with 1 or more elements) and `List` doesn't have `Id` field hence that error.

You would need to get the value and loop through items in that list and act upon those items individually.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to use if as the key even though the values are test with a space?

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having is that the accountAtsMap2.get(ATName) was returning a list.  Therefore, I needed to use:  accountAtsMap2.get(ATName)[0].id

Thanks!